# Structure inter-dependant feature flags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, architecture, featuretoggle, launchdarkly

I'm fairly new to feature flags. They have been super helpful. I'm using them to release features but I am also using them to AB test features in the app.

The problem I am running into is that some features are dependant on others. For example, I have an onboarding module. If I turn the profile page module off it will break the onboarding module since part of the onboarding experience involves an introduction to the profile page. Contrived example, but you get the idea. Some features depend on others. If I turn the profile page module off I want it to automatically shut down any connected features. So I can never be in a state where the profile page module is off and the onboarding module is on.

I'm assuming I am not the first person to run into this problem. Before I work on my own custom solution to this problem I was wondering if there is there a standard approach to dealing with this issue? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're using LaunchDarkly since you mentioned coming up with a custom solution, but since this question is tagged with `launchdarkly`, I wanted to make sure that you were aware of the [flag pre-requisites](https://docs.launchdarkly.com/home/managing-flags/flag-prerequisites) feature. This should address your main concern here.

*Disclaimer: I work at LaunchDarkly*